# Тест для на Django REST API fraemwork

Tags: тестирование, django-rest-framework

Пишу функциональный тест

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

__all__ = ['OAuthTestCase']

ADDRESS_FOR_TEST = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/request/'


class ApiOAuthTestCase(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create_user(username=user_name, password=user_password)

        self.my_message = {
            'grant_type': 'password',
            'username': "user_name",
            'password': "user_password",
            'client_id': "secret_ket",
            'client_secret': "clietn_id",
        }

    def test_token(self):
        response = self.client.post(ADDRESS_FOR_TEST, self.my_message)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

При прохождении данного теста появляется ошибка `400`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить доступ к содержимому ответа из `response`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доступ к содержимому ответа получается через: `response.content`